# Neo4j v2 stop windows service - non clean shutdown detected

Tags: service, cmd, neo4j, backup, shutdown

How can i properly stop the Neo4j Windows Service cleanly? I have Neo4j(v2 - Community) running as a windows service. What i'm trying to do is take a back up of the data files.

Currently i have written a batch file which will... 
- shut down the service
- backup the data files
- restart the service

The problem is that after restarting the service and i check the log files the following message is logged(see below) - Although the db recovers i'm concerned at some point it may get corrupted due to the "non clean shutdown"

```
2014-05-14 18:35:41.993+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:41.997+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db.names] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=38b)
2014-05-14 18:35:41.999+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.000+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.relationshiptypestore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=0b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.000+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.strings non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.000+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.strings] brickCount=0 brickSize=79616b mappedMem=79691776b (storeSize=128b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.001+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.001+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index.keys] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=38b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.002+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.002+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.index] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=0b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.003+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.arrays non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.003+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db.arrays] brickCount=0 brickSize=90112b mappedMem=90177536b (storeSize=128b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.008+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.008+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.propertystore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=943697b mappedMem=94371840b (storeSize=0b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.010+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.relationshipstore.db non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.010+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.relationshipstore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=1153416b mappedMem=115343360b (storeSize=0b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.011+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.nodestore.db non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.011+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore.nodestore.db] brickCount=0 brickSize=26208b mappedMem=26214400b (storeSize=9b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.012+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore non clean shutdown detected
2014-05-14 18:35:42.013+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.n.s.StoreFactory]: [C:\NEO4J-~1.7\data\graph.db\neostore] brickCount=0 brickSize=0b mappedMem=0b (storeSize=54b)
2014-05-14 18:35:42.028+0000 INFO  [o.n.k.i.t.x.XaLogicalLog]: Non clean shutdown detected on log [C:\neo4j-community-1.9.7\data\graph.db\nioneo_logical.log.1]. Recovery started ...
```

and below is the batch file itself

```
@echo off
rem Batch file to backup Neo4j data files
rem Accepts one parameter [prod|qa] which is the name of the folder to backup

set instance=%1%
set services=E:\neo4j\%instance%\
set source_path=F:\neo4j\%instance%\data
set destination_path=E:\neo4j_data_backups\%instance%\%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%
set robocopy_log_file=E:\neo4j_data_backups\%instance%\backup_%date:~10,4%%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%.log

rem check to make sure the source folder exists - otherwise quit
if not exist %source_path% goto :badargument

rem if call "%services%bin\Neo4jInstaller.bat" status == "RUNNING"

rem Stop the Neo4j Service before the backup
echo Stopping service: Neo4j-Server-%instance%
sc stop Neo4j-Server-%instance%

rem Copy the data folder
echo Backing up data from %source_path% to %destination_path%
robocopy %source_path% %destination_path% /E /LOG+:%robocopy_log_file%

rem Start the Neo4j Service again after the data backup
echo Starting service: Neo4j-Server-%instance%
sc start Neo4j-Server-%instance%

rem lets zip the file now
echo Zipping the backup content: %destination_path%.zip
7z a -tzip %destination_path%.zip %destination_path% > NUL:

rem delete the backup folder
echo Deleting the backup folder after zip
rd /s/q %destination_path%

echo #### Backup Completed ####
goto :eof
```

Comment: I would assume that you are restarting the Windows host service which may be killing the Neo4j database process before restarting it. The host service needs to wait until shutdown procedures are complete and available heap is written to disc. Please provide batch file source.

Comment: Hey @KennyBastani - i'm using the stop service command (sc) as noted in the batch file (see updated information) - this was based on the guide [link]http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-installation.html - just to be clear the "non clean shutdown" message actually gets logged when the windows service is restarted again